# What would happen if a server (Windows 2008) is updated to use TLS 1.2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, tls

If a user using Firefox browses to a website on a server (Windows 2008) that has been updated to use TLS 1.2, what would happen? As I am a newbie to this can someone explain what the process is when a SSL or TLS handshake occurs and what potential problems can arise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL protocol versions generally are not exclusive – the same server may offer TLS 1.2, 1.1, 1.0, SSL 3.0, and even SSL 2.0 for the ancients. Problems only occur if the client and server have no supported versions in common. In other words, a typical upgrade would not affect older clients.

Comment: What do you meany by `Problems only occur if the client and server have no supported versions in common`?

Comment: Reading the 'Description' section of the article about TLS at https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security, it states that `From this list, the server picks the strongest cipher and hash function that it also supports and notifies the client of the decision`. What does this mean exactly? Is this based on registry changes to the server?